# Keyczar: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'errors' in Python 3.8

Tags: python, django, encryption

I'm using [django-encrypted-fields](https://github.com/defrex/django-encrypted-fields) to encrypt models in the database, but I'm getting the **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'errors'** from **keyczar**, is there a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'errors'` error when using `python-keyczar`.

In my case the error is from `... Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keyczar/keyczar.py, line 26`

This fails because the `import errors` statement on that line is using an "implicit relative import", which is not supported in python 3. You could fix this specific error by adding the keyczar directory to the PYTHONPATH so python can find this and the other modules that it imports in this way. But the real problem here is that you are using a python 2 module from python 3 and you'll run into other issues after fixing this one, because there are many other incompatibilities between between python 2 and 3.

There is a "python3-keyczar" keyczar module in pip (note the "3"). Using this module with python3 worked for me. So depending on your situation (I know nothing about django) the fix is using either python 2(.7) or uninstalling python-keyczar and installing python3-keyczar.

Note that keyczar is no longer maintained (see: https://github.com/google/keyczar)

Comment: Do we also need to include anything on the `requirements.txt` file?

Answer (score -1):

python-keyczar

u installed this ??

check: pip list

or install

pip install python-keyczar